# How to justify studies on fractal cosmology?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, symmetry, cosmological-inflation, fractals

What are the arguments (theoretical and experimental) to support or to justify a fractal distribution of matter on all scales in cosmology?

I see only one justification:

On some small scales, matter is hierarchical : Local gravitation makes matter clumps into stars, star clusters, galaxies, groups of galaxies and super clusters of galaxies.  It takes time to form such structures, and the universe isn't old enough to had time to built super structures and Mega Super Structures on *all* scales.  Thus, the matter distribution should be perfectly *isotropic* and *uniform* on a very Large Scale.  This is the essence of the *cosmological principle* (which may be false, since it's just a theoretical principle).  If present, the Mega Super Structures on all the larger scales (i.e the *fractal distribution*) must have been already present at the Big Bang itself, and would be a *primodial fractal super structure*.  In this case, the cosmological principle would be false and the FLRW metric (which assumes the cosmological principle) would be completelly useless.  What could justify this distribution?

Is the *inflation theory* compatible with a fractal distribution of matter at the Big Bang level itself?  Could the fractal distribution just be an arbitrary initial condition to be imposed, independantly of the inflation theory?

Comment: There's a [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_cosmology) on this with lots of references: that might be a good place to start.

Comment: Related question : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7483/if-the-universe-were-a-fractal

Comment: Another related question : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/306073/what-processes-created-the-initial-anisotropies-in-the-energy-density-distrbut?rq=1